# MVC EF (Code First) - Creating relationship with AspNetUsers and Custom Tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

new to MVC and EF. Trying to achieve the following:

- A new site with individual user accounts
- Create a DB table "Leagues" whereby when creating a new league the LeagueAdmin is an ApplicationUser

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) to try to achieve what i wanted. When i start the application I am able to register new users without issue. However, when I go to create a new league I get the following error:

**"Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations."**

I have tried many fixes i've read about but they tend to lead me down a path of increasingly complex errors. I feel like this should be simple enough that i'd like to understand this error first before tackling the next.

[VS Project Source is here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/50kux2ymzy3p6dg/EF3.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, your database does not contain a _MigrationHistory table.

Add this code to your DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
}
```

Go to **Package Manager Console** by following *View -> Other Windows -> Package Manager Console*

And write following commands:

```
enable-migrations
add-migration InitialCreate
update-database
```

Alternatively;

You can add this code to your DbContext;

```
static LeagueContext()
{
  Database.SetInitializer<LeagueContext>(
new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<LeagueContext>());
}
```